# Can I parallelise an operation driven by a flatMap?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, functional-programming, rx-java, rx-android

Say I have a method like the code below, in which a List is flatMapped to individual strings, each of which has some expensive operation applied to them. Is there any way to parallelise the expensive operations, in the same way that I'd use parallelStream() in Java 8?

```
final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Ringo");
        add("John");
        add("Paul");
        add("George");
    }};

    Observable.just(names).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<String>, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call(final List<String> names) {
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                            for (String name : names) {
                                subscriber.onNext(name);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(String s) {
                    //Simulate expensive operation
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(6000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return s.toUpperCase();
                }
            }).subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            Log.v("RXExample", s + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
```

For completion, applying the change recommended in the answer looks like the following and works nicely!

```
final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Ringo");
        add("John");
        add("Paul");
        add("George");
    }};

    Observable.just(names).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<String>, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call(final List<String> names) {
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(final Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                            for (final String name : names) {
                                Observable
                                        .just(name)
                                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)))
                                        .map(new Func1<String, String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public String call(String s) {
                                                //Simulate expensive operation
                                                try {
                                                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                                return s.toUpperCase();
                                            }
                                        }).subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted() {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(String s) {
                                        subscriber.onNext(name);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            Log.v("RXExample", s + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can parallelise work with flatMap as in the following example. I am using RxJava2 for testing.

For further explanation please read the flatMap usage from here: http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.de/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Ringo");
        add("John");
        add("Paul");
        add("George");
    }};

    Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.fromIterable(names)
            .flatMap(s -> {
                return longWork(s).doOnNext(s1 -> {
                    printCurrentThread(s1);
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
            });

    TestObserver<String> test = stringObservable.test();

    test.awaitDone(2_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).assertValueCount(4);
}

private Observable<String> longWork(String s) throws InterruptedException {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(1_000);

        return s;
    });
}

private void printCurrentThread(String additional) {
    System.out.println(additional + "_" + Thread.currentThread());
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I've applied it to my code snippet to show how it would look in AndroidRX.